# .htaccess RewriteRule не работает

Tags: .htaccess, apache, index

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/post/([0-9])/$ index.php?post=$1 [L]
Options -Indexes
```

Вот такое у меня правило, пробую перейти на сайт localhost/post/1/
У меня говорит 404, может в правиле я что-то не так написал хелпаните плз =3

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/company/sprinthost/blog/129560/

Comment: Знаю я как он работает.

Comment: попробуйте RewriteRule ^post/([0-9])/$ index.php?post=$1 [L]

Comment: Это хорошо, что Вы знаете :) Просто очень полезная ссылка и в самом начале статьи ответ на Ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первому RewriteRule передается путь от того места, где находится .htaccess, до запрошенного файла. Эта строка никогда не начинается со "/".

Таким образом, в RewriteRule у вас будет `post/1/` (без слеша в начале), что не совпадет с вашей ругуляркой.

Чтобы все заработало, вам нужно:

1. Указать регулярку без слеша в начале.
2. Прописать `RewriteBase /`, чтобы избежать артефактов с переадресацией.

Итого должно получиться:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^post/([0-9])/$ index.php?post=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Вместо `[0-9]` можно использовать `\d`. А чтобы была возможность указать не только число от `0` до `9`, а вообще любые, можно использовать `\d+`.